# Erro de ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. ao gerar csv com python

Tags: python

O meu código está dando erro de `"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."`

e não consigo achar em nenhum fórum, alguém sabe o que pode ser ? Obrigado.

```
import json
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://api.suthubservice.com/v0/sales' 
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 
 'api_key' : 'eb9484921d678843bbfdd6bf460a1df7' 
} 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
res = json.loads(response.text)

output = []

for contract in res['response']: # tomei a liberdade de mudar o nome da variável
     if len(contract['policies']) > 0:
         for profile in contract['policies'][0]['covered_goods']:
             output.append(profile['Nome'])

totais = {x:output.count(x) for x in output}

with open('C:\Desafio\cadastro.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    spamwriter.writerow(['nome_pet'] + ['contador'])


for nome,qtde in totais.items():
    spamwriter.writerow([nome]+[qtde])


for nome,qtde in totais.items():
    print(nome,qtde)
```

Comment: Você deixou o comentário que eu fiz no post passado no seu código. Dá mais uma olhada naquele post porque eu fiz uma modificação pra pegar todos os nomes caso o `contract` tenha mais de um elemento `policies`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse erro acontece porque ao final de `with: open(...) as csvfile:` o arquivo aberto é fechado. Daí logo em seguida você entra em um `for` que tenta gravar nesse arquivo que já foi fechado.

Coloque esse `for` dentro do `with`. Assim:

```
with open('C:\Desafio\cadastro.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csvfile: 
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';') 
    spamwriter.writerow(['nome_pet'] + ['contador']) 
    for nome,qtde in totais.items(): 
        spamwriter.writerow([nome]+[qtde])
```

Comment: Rafael, muito obrigado! estou começando agora na linguagem e tem algumas regras que não conhecia! Gratidão!

Comment: Uma dica: se uma resposta te ajudou e resolveu o problema exposto @Gleice marque o V nela para que as outras pessoas que acessarem aqui posteriormente saberem que a solução solucionou o problema. Assim, quando outra pessoa com um problema parecido chegar aqui, vai saber que com a resposta dada o problema foi resolvido e que elas podem tentar o mesmo método para resolver o delas.